# Remove pattern between two symbols that exist more than once in single line

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a number of files similar to the following file (which I will call `file1`):

```
(((1824663.AST0201.AST0202.AST0016...AST0087:0.2575,225845.AST0201.AST0202.AST0016...AST0087:0.717227):0.45328,190304.AST0201.AST0202.AST0016...AST0087:...........
```

I wanted to remove all `AST*`, between the `.` before `AST*` and the `:`, which always follow after the last `.AST*`. This pattern appear a lot on one line. The `AST*` shown here is repeated in exact, but I have whole lot more such line with different `AST`.

What I currently doing is splitting the file, remove all `AST`, then connect each line into one.

```
sed 's/:/:\n/g;s/,/,\n/g' file1 | sed 's/\.AST.*:/:/g' | sed -z 's/\n//g'
```

Expected output:

```
(((1824663:0.2575,225845:0.717227):0.45328,190304:...........
```

Are there any shorter command in calling `sed` for this?

Comment: When asking a question on text processing, please be sure to include not only an example of the input, but also the corresponding desired output, so that contributors can verify their solutions against your example.

Comment: What sort of intervening pattern is seen, if any? From your example, it's unclear if `AST` is separated occasionally by a literal `...` three dots or not. Also, do you mean `*` to represent a digit, only? If you meant to write a Regex, you're `AST*` represents a literal `A` followed by a literal `S` followed by zero-or-more `T`s.

Comment: @jubilatious1 The `...` in between of `AST*` was to show there are a number of `.AST` in between instead of `...` literally. I was intended to remove everything in between all `\.AST up to the first following :`, regardless of what's in between. I was stumbled on the `sed` command as I didn't know how to specify the removal at the first following `:` after each `AST` batch, Thanks for the respond anyway! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/\.AST[^:]*//g' input_file
(((1824663:0.2575,225845:0.717227):0.45328,190304:...........
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you mind to elaborate on the command? What did the `[^:]` do here?

Comment: The command will match a literal period `.` with AST beside it, then everything up to the next occurance of a semi colon `[^:]*' but not including the semi colon @web.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -pe  's:g/ [ AST \d+ ]+ % \.+ //;'  file
```

Sample Input:

```
(((1824663.AST0201.AST0202.AST0016...AST0087:0.2575,225845.AST0201.AST0202.AST0016...AST0087:0.717227):0.45328,190304.AST0201.AST0202.AST0016...AST0087:...........
```

Sample Output:

```
(((1824663.:0.2575,225845.:0.717227):0.45328,190304.:...........
```

Raku is a Perl-family programming language. Here, the familiar `-pe` autoprinting linewise flags are used (sed-like). The Regex above is written assuming that the `.` dot is a record or element separator. Therefore it makes more sense not to look for `.AST` but to leave the leading `.` dot untouched.

A new feature of Raku regexes is the modified quantifier for repeating elements. Simply put, if you have a pattern like  `AST \d+`, you can group it with brackets to make `[ AST \d+ ]`, then add a quantifier to indicate the number of repeats: `[ AST \d+ ]+`.

Normally the above would just recognize multiple instances of the pattern all run-together, however you can now follow the pattern with a *modified quantifer* indicator `% \.+` to indicate the `[ AST \d+ ]` pattern `%` ("is separated by") `\.+` one-or-more `.` dots. This construct avoids the problem seen when using just an optional `\.?` regex, namely that the separator is lost and patterns like `AST0AST1` (if authentic) are deleted. Furthermore, the modified quantifier can be used to delete all-but-the-first or all-but-the-last targeted element(s):

Sample Input:

```
echo '(((1824663.AST0101:AST0201.AST0202:AST301.AST302.AST303:AST0401.AST0402.AST0403.AST0404:)))' > test_AST.txt
```

One-liners and Output (spaces inserted):

```perl
~$ raku -pe  's:g/ [ AST \d+ ]+  //;' test_AST.txt
(((1824663.:.:..:...:)))
 
~$ raku -pe  's:g/ [ AST \d+ ]+ % \.  //;' test_AST.txt
(((1824663.::::)))
 
~$ raku -pe  's:g/ [ AST \d+ ]**2..* % \.  //;' test_AST.txt
(((1824663.AST0101::::)))
 
~$ raku -pe  's:g/ [ AST \d+ ]**3..* % \.  //;' test_AST.txt
(((1824663.AST0101:AST0201.AST0202:::)))
 
~$ raku -pe  's:g/ [ AST \d+ ]**4..* % \.  //;' test_AST.txt
(((1824663.AST0101:AST0201.AST0202:AST301.AST302.AST303::)))
 
~$ raku -pe  's:g/ [ AST \d+ ]**5..* % \.  //;' test_AST.txt
(((1824663.AST0101:AST0201.AST0202:AST301.AST302.AST303:AST0401.AST0402.AST0403.AST0404:)))
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org